# group_by and group_by_ in pipes

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, nse

I am writing a function that can group and concatenate variables using the dplyr package:

```
basket<-function(dataframe, group, target)
{
  dataframe %>% 
    group_by_(group) %>% 
    summarise(new_target=paste(as.character(target), collapse="_"))

}
```

I am using the mtcars dataset for testing:

```
basket(mtcars, mtcars$am, mtcars$wt)
```

The desired output should be something like this:

```
am     wt
0      2.62_2.875_2.32...
1      3.215_3.19_3.44...
```

However, in my code the group_by_ function fails to successfully create groups based on "am". The result I get is simply a concatenated string of all values of "wt":

```
[1] "2.62_2.875_2.32_3.215_3.44_3.46_3.57_3.19_3.15_3.44_3.44_4.07_3.73_3.78...
```

If I use group_by then I'll receive this error:

```
stop(structure(list(message = "unknown variable to group by : group", 
call = resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)), cppstack = structure(list(
    file = "", line = -1L, stack = "C++ stack not available on this system"), .Names = c("file", 
"line", "stack"), class = "Rcpp_stack_trace")), .Names = c("message",  ...
```

Has anybody seen this problem before?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Please see updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the SE versions of both `group_by` and `summarise`, and supply the values quoted (`""`). Don't use dollar notation with `dplyr` when referring to variables in the data.frame at hand.

```
basket<-function(dataframe, group, target) {
  dataframe %>% 
    group_by_(group) %>% 
    summarise_(new_target = lazyeval::interp(~paste(as.character(x), collapse="_"), 
                                             x = as.name(target)))
}

basket(mtcars, "am", "wt")
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 × 2
>      am                                                                                           new_target
>   <dbl>                                                                                                <chr>
> 1     0 3.215_3.44_3.46_3.57_3.19_3.15_3.44_3.44_4.07_3.73_3.78_5.25_5.424_5.345_2.465_3.52_3.435_3.84_3.845
> 2     1                                 2.62_2.875_2.32_2.2_1.615_1.835_1.935_2.14_1.513_3.17_2.77_3.57_2.78
> ```

Also see `vignette('nse')`.

Comment: Thank you Axeman! I guessed it was group_by_ can't recognize the variable as a name but I didn't know how to fix it. This is doing exactly the right job!